# Redirect in OnActionExecuting not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to redirect a visitor which isn't authenticated via OnactionExecuting() so that it covers my entire controller, but it's almost like it's being skipped entirely. Is it possible to redirect from within OnActionExecuting()?

```
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    if (SimpleAuth.isAuth())
    {
        RedirectToAction("Login", "Users");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `RedirectToAction` inside filters. `RedirectToAction` is a member of the `Controller` class. That's why you can call this method inside action methods which are the members of the class which inherits from `Controller` class.

But, if we are talking about filters, then you must set `filterContext.Result` to a new `RedirectToRouteResult`:

```
 filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(
                                new
                                {
                                    controller = "Users",
                                    action = "Login"
                                }));
```

Comment: Although it is redirecting now, it redirects to / and not /Users/Login